# deleting an image in a mean stack application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

i want to delete the images that i uploaded in the server but every time i get an error
and only the element in the mongodb document are being deleted
this is my code

```
exports.removeImage = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    fs.unlinkSync('./images/'+req.filename);
    const deleteImage = await Image.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
    
    res.json({ message: 'deleted Image successfully' });
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
  }
}
```

i think the problem is in req.filename its returning an undifiened value i tried req.body.filename but still no result

Answer (score 0):

i resolved the problem by adding

```
 const image = await Image.findById(req.params.id)
```

then i used image.filename in fs.unlinkSync

this is the result :

```
exports.removeImage = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const image = await Image.findById(req.params.id)
    fs.unlinkSync('./images/'+image.filename);
    const deleteImage = await Image.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
    
    res.json({ message: 'deleted Inspecstib successfully' });
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
  }
}
```